# Arch component : ViewModel is not retained after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

**Why After screen rotation a new ViewModel is always provided for fragment when we create ViewModel in onAttach?**

I tried to dig in my side, but I could not find the answer what I noticed is that:
The ViewModels are stored in a ViewModelStore, which is held by HolderFragment.
This HolderFragment is marked as retain a fragment so he must survive to the configuration change and onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach () still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).

But in our case onDestroy is called and the ViewModelStore is cleared . as you can see in HolderFragment#onDestory method

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mViewModelStore.clear();
    }
```

If my analysis is good the real question is why HolderFragment#onDestroy is called after the configuration change even if he is marked as retain ?

The same problem has been fixed [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/issues/49) and you will find my comment.

Comment: "Why After screen rotation a new ViewModel is always provided for fragment when we create ViewModel in onAttach?" -- please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem. I haven't used `onAttach()` as the point of creating the `ViewModel`, but I have had no problems with the `ViewModel` being retained across configuration changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare the same problem has been fixed here : https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/issues/49 and you will find my comment

Comment: @Casablancais i have my VM onCreate in `support.v4.app.Fragment` but still new VM is created upon screen rotation.